# How to reuse a widget tree from a glade file with GtkBuilder?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade, gtkbuilder

i want to populate a gtk.notebook on-the-fly. everytime a user opens a file, a new notebook-tab is generated. pretty straight forward. my problem is, that i use glade to build the ui and the notebook-tab should have a child widget tree (scrolledwindow->viewport-> alignment->frame). in my glade-file, i have a template notebook-tab, which i want to use multiple times, so that i dont have to code the whole tree in plain gtk. with libglade, you could reuse a widget tree as explained in the pygtk faq here: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq22.011.htp&req=show . How do i do this with GtkBuilder?

thanks in advance,

Arthur

Comment: Did you by any chance manage to use the Builder.connect method more than once (i.e.: calling it again after you added the extra widget)? If yes, how did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way with GtkBuilder:

```
builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("GUI.xml")
builder.connect_signals(self)
self.window1 = builder.get_object("window1")
self.window1.show()
```

**edit:**

I was initially wrong, it seems that gtkbuilder does instantiate objects when it adds. So the ideal way to do this would be to add the widget in manually via a string

```
builder.add_from_string("""
<interface>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <child>
      <object class="GtkComboBox" id="combobox1">
        <property name="model">liststore1</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>""")

self.window1 = builder.get_object("window1")
```

Hopefully this works!

Comment: well, this only adds the object "window1" once, but i need do instantiate another or multiple object(s) with the name "window1"

Comment: could you try doing `self.window2 = builder.get_object("window1")`? I thought that it instantiates a new object for you. I will test this when I get back home :)

Comment: nope, doesnt work. i tried that and it returns the same object.

Comment: You were right, check the edit, http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-devel-list@gnome.org/msg06030.html

Comment: thanks for the edit! not the answer i hoped to get, but it will do the job! thanks again.